# Synology mysterious duplicate folder

Tags: ssh, nas, dropbox, synology

I'm syncing up my Dropbox and my Synology using Cloud Sync. In CloudSync I see the task is set to use `/homes/<myUserName>` as a destination folder.

In Synology's File Station, I see that `/homes/<myUserName>` contains my DropBox files, but I also see another folder called `home` which seems to contain the same files.

Now that's weird because I don't know where those files are coming from. I'm not even sure if that folder is real because when I ssh into the NAS, I don't see it anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "/homes" folder is the storage of "home directories" which users get mounted as their "/home" upon their login into DSM.

i.e.: User logged in as "ventsyv" can access his "/homes/ventsyv" as "/home" within the DSM GUI.

If user "ventsyv" runs "pwd" after the login to SSH shell, the result will be "/var/services/homes/ventsyv" which contains data from his home dir as well.

(refers to DSM 6.1)